# UnicodeEncodeError when trying to read a graph with networkx

Tags: python, unicode, networkx

I have a little script that takes hashtags from Twitter with the TwitterSearch API and uses them as nodes in a graph with networkx. TwitterSearch returns the hashtags in unicode format, and I have no problems while saving the graph using the `write_pajek` function. Instead, when I try to read the graph with `read_pajek`, it returns me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in read_pajek
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 263, in _open_file
    result = func(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\pajek.py", line 134, in read_pajek
    return parse_pajek(lines)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\readwrite\pajek.py", line 170, in parse_pajek
    splitline=shlex.split(str(next(lines)))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I think the problem is due to the fact that it tries to decode with the ascii codec some chinese/japanese characters, but I don't know how solve it. In the second argument of the function, you can declare the encoding of the file, which by default is "UTF-8", so in theory I shouldn't have any problem while reading it.

Comment: It looks like a bug (or maybe feature) that Python's shlex.split can't handle unicode.  This could be fixed fairly simply I think.

Comment: This may fix it https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/1190

Comment: I have NetworkX 2.0 installed but I still get the same error. The error raises for a string node that contains the carachter "é"